# CKReference List update

Tags: ios, swift, icloud, ckrecord

I have a CKRecord with a CKReferenceList field. I want to add an additional CKReference to the CKReferenceList... I found this reference in stack overflow that gives a stellar example of how to download list from a CKReference List.

```
 var ksubs:[CKRecordID] = []
        for kSubscribers in record?.objectForKey("rexReferenced")  as! [CKReference] {
            ksubs.append(kSubscribers.recordID)
        }
```

But I need to do the inverse, I want to add an additional element to an existing CKreferenceList list. What is the CK equivalent to .append element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bon, managed to figure out how to ask the right question and found the answer here.

[How to modify CloudKit Reference Lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29988207/how-to-modify-cloudkit-reference-lists)

Its obvious isn't it.

```
CKReference *reference = [[CKReference alloc] initWithRecord:connectionRecord action:CKReferenceActionNone];
            NSMutableArray *list_a = [record_a[@"connections"] mutableCopy];
            if (!list_a) list_a = [NSMutableArray array];
            [list_a addObject:reference];
            record_a[@"connections"] = list_a;
```